# What is specifically the correct Generator output type?

Tags: neural-networks

[image]

I was constructing a GAN to analyze samples of timeseries with 3 features using a previous working template, and ran into the strangest error I haven't seen before. Some of my research so far suggests it has something to do with the batch size, but I think I need more help interpreting the error.

```
NetTrain::invgenunsp: Generator function did not produce data of the correct type.
```

I've used `Tanh` as an output before (I went back and checked the other notebook). When individually initialized my discriminator processes my generator as expected. This matches my previous experience with GANs in the Wolfram Language. There is a one to one correspondence between the Generator and Discriminator and my input matrixes match. The docs state that matrixes are valid inputs into `Generators` & `Discriminators`. I've tried switching around the final layers of the generator but maybe there is a combination I haven't tried yet if there is one to be suggested?

```
GAN = NetInitialize@NetGANOperator[{generator, discriminator}]
BATCHSIZE = 8;
datagen = 
  Function[<|"Sample" -> RandomSample[trainingData, BATCHSIZE], 
    "Latent" -> Table[noise, BATCHSIZE]|>];
trained = NetTrain[GAN, datagen, All,
  TrainingUpdateSchedule -> {"Generator", "Discriminator"},
  BatchSize -> BATCHSIZE
  ]
```

**More info:**
As I try to simply the problem, I'm thinking more and more this is a bug? I can chain the nets predictably but when I try to evaluate this chain in `NetTrain` I continue to get the above stated error.

```
gnet = NetInitialize@generator;
dnet = NetInitialize@discriminator;
Table[dnet[gnet[noise]], 10]

(* {0.243106, 0.251533, 0.3477, 0.317092, 0.260215, 0.158646, 0.381327, 0.33943, 0.382698, 0.721124} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are examples of the above code in the docs, Wolfram Support was able to guide me to a solution. For whatever reason, the training data doesn't need to be in the form of a `Function`, and I was able to train the net with the following code. That explains why I was able to get the `discriminator` to digest the generator output smoothly, but `NetTrain` wasn't able to parse the training data input and outputs.

```
trained = NetTrain[
  GAN,
  <|"Sample" -> RandomSample[trainingData, BATCHSIZE], 
   "Latent" -> Table[noise, BATCHSIZE]|>,
  BatchSize -> BATCHSIZE
  ]
```